# Connecting to local MySQL database doesnt work after creating an .exe with jLink + jPackage

Tags: java, mysql, jlink, jpackage

**Enivronment**:
OpenJDK 11, JavaFX 11, MySQL 8.0, Gradle 6.2.2, IntellijIDEA ,Windows 8.1

**Problem:**
When I run my program inside the IDE it works fine and connects to the database without problems, but once I try to run the .exe built with jLink and jPackage it shows an error.

**Some code from the class "ConnectionManager" used to connect to the local MySQL database:**

```
    final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", user = "root", password = "password", databaseName = "sifana";
    final String databaseNameWithTimezone = databaseName + "?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC";
    public static Connection connection;


    private Connection createDatabase() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "create database if not exists sifana";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + "?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC", user, password);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        statement.close();
        return connection;
    }
```

**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version "5.0.0"
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.17.2'
}

group 'yayarh'
version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'
mainClassName = "$moduleName/yayarh.Launcher"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation group: 'com.jfoenix', name: 'jfoenix', version: '9.0.9'
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.19'
    implementation group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '11.0.0'
}


application {
    'yayarh.Launcher'
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix",
                                 "--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix",
                                 "--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=com.jfoenix",
                                 "--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=com.jfoenix",
                                 "--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix",
                                 "--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=com.jfoenix"]
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

jlink {
    launcher {
        name = 'Sifana'
        jvmArgs = applicationDefaultJvmArgs
    }
    jpackage {
        installerOptions = [
                '--description', 'Place a description here',
                '--copyright', 'All copyrights to...',
                '--vendor', 'vendor',
        ]

        installerType = project.findProperty('installerType')

        if (installerType == 'msi') {
            imageOptions += ['--icon', 'src/main/resources/yayarh/images/sifana_ico.ico']
            installerOptions += [
                    '--win-per-user-install', '--win-dir-chooser',
                    '--win-menu', '--win-shortcut'
            ]
        }

    }
}

jpackage {
    doFirst {
        project.getProperty('installerType') // throws exception if its missing
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": 'yayarh.Launcher'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}

javafx {
    version = '11'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}
```

**The error stacktrace:**

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)

        at sifana/yayarh.classes.ConnectionManager.createDatabase(ConnectionMana
ger.java:25)
        at sifana/yayarh.classes.ConnectionManager.initiateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:18)
        at sifana/yayarh.Main.start(Main.java:25)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:338)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:777)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.ja
va:486)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1340)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)

        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:336)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
        at yayarh.merged.module/com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:329)
        ... 24 more
```

Please note that it works perfectly when running from the IDE.

Comment: It appears to be having difficulty creating a SSL/TLS connection. Is the keystore/truststore in the jar?

Comment: @Jason thanks for your answer, I didn't configure SSL when I setup MySQL server so I don't have any keys to use, but your answer helped me to solve the problem, all I had to do was to add "useSSL=false" to my connection url, now the problem is solved, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when using JPackage as well, I received SSLHandshakeExceptions after exporting but not within the IDE itself. This error occurs because of the way Java 11 uses TLSv1.3 which works unexpectedly when jpackage has exported. Here's how I fixed it. When creating a SSL connection, you need to force TLSv1.2.

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());

SocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

/* Use the socketFactory to initialize your SSL connection */

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply, but the issue is already solved as I wrote in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

I realize the OP had his problem solved, but I was led to this thread with the exact same problem.  And, I didn't see any other similar threads.  The two suggestions above didn't help me.

I was able to solve my problem.  It turned out I was missing the statement "    requires mysql.connector.java;" in the modules-info manifest file.  That was causing jpackage not to include the driver in the final build.

I could successfully run the program with the Gradle "run" task.  However, the connection would fail running the installed version I'd made using jpackage.